# Mediawiki - Bulk upload new version of images

Tags: upload, mediawiki

I would like upload larger number of images to the mediawiki. It should support uploading newer version of files, if they are already uploaded.
I tried using the extension UploadLocal. However, it seems it doesn't support uploading as newer versions.

Any help much appreciated.

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0):

[Extension:MsUpload](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MsUpload).

Include `$wgMSU_confirmReplace = true; // Show the "Replace file?" checkbox` in LocalSettings.php

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. But I included that. However I could not see the replace file checkbox. I am getting the message that "The file already exists". Am I missing anything?